# How can I insert the contents of a file into a string variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services

[image]

I am developing a Windows Service in VB.NET. I have added a two new .xsl files in my project.

My problem is that file: how can I insert that file into a particular string?

```
Dim CTD As String = ??
```

I need to call that CTD.xsl in the above line of code. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Just to make it clear: You want to read the content of the XSL file in to CTD?

Comment: yes xactly i need that file into tht CTD string

Answer (score 3):

In C#:

```
string xslContents = File.ReadAllText("CTD.xsl");
```

You need to make sure the file is actually present where you're reading it from, obviously (you might need to copy it to the output directory of your solution when you build)